# How to cause invalidation when removing index from reactiveValues in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This [post](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2439) proposes a way to remove an index from a `reactiveValues`. However, this solution does not cause invalidation. How can I adapt `remove_reactive_values_index()` such that it will trigger invalidation of the reactive value `rv`?

In the example below I would like all outputs dependent on `rv` (`ui_select` and `verbatim`) to be triggered when removing an index from `rv` by clicking on the `rmv_index` button. How can I achieve that? Importantly, I want to avoid using lists (`rv <- reactiveValues(a_list = list())`) or the `update*` functions.

```
library(shiny)

# Adapted from https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2439
remove_reactive_values_index <- function(reactive_val, index) {
  # Access the internal structure of the reactiveValues object
  rv_r6 <- .subset2(reactive_val, "impl")
  # Remove the reactive value
  dummy <- rv_r6$.values$remove(index)
  # Update the order of names in the reactiveValues object
  rv_r6$.nameOrder <- setdiff(rv_r6$.nameOrder, index)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('gen_index', 'Create new index'),
  actionButton('rmv_index', 'Remove index'),
  uiOutput('ui_select'),
  verbatimTextOutput('verbatim')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$gen_index, {
    new_index <- paste(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
    rv[[new_index]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$rmv_index, {
    remove_reactive_values_index(rv, input$select_index)
  })
  
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = names(rv))
  })
  
  output$verbatim <- renderPrint({
    str(reactiveValuesToList(rv))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution by creating a dummy index to invalidate the `rv`. This is not ideal as it makes the code cumbersome. Ideally only `remove_reactive_values_index()` would need to be modified so that it causes invalidation.

```
library(shiny)

# Adapted from https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2439
remove_reactive_values_index <- function(reactive_val, index) {
  # Access the internal structure of the reactiveValues object
  rv_r6 <- .subset2(reactive_val, "impl")
  # Remove the reactive value
  dummy <- rv_r6$.values$remove(index)
  # Update the order of names in the reactiveValues object
  rv_r6$.nameOrder <- setdiff(rv_r6$.nameOrder, index)
  reactive_val$dummy <- rnorm(10)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('gen_index', 'Create new index'),
  actionButton('rmv_index', 'Remove index'),
  uiOutput('ui_select'),
  verbatimTextOutput('verbatim')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$gen_index, {
    new_index <- paste(sample(letters, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = '')
    rv[[new_index]] <- rnorm(1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$rmv_index, {
    remove_reactive_values_index(rv, input$select_index)
  })
  
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    rv_list <- reactiveValuesToList(rv)
    rv_list <- rv_list[!names(rv_list) %in% 'dummy']
    updated_choices <- names(rv_list)
    selectInput('select_index', 'Select index', choices = updated_choices)
  })
  
  output$verbatim <- renderPrint({
    rv_list <- reactiveValuesToList(rv)
    rv_list <- rv_list[!names(rv_list) %in% 'dummy']
    str(rv_list)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```